# Define function in Mathematica with previous output

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica and stuck with the following problem:

Suppose I do some computation like Integrate[x^2,x]. How can I use the output to define a new function?

So, intuitively I thought it should look somehow like

f[x_] := Integrate[x,x]

but that doesn't work, for example, I'd expect f[1] = 1/2 but I get as output simply f[1].

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[a_] := Integrate[x^2, x] /. x -> a

f[1]
```

> 1/3

Answer (score 2):

This is more efficient, also using the syntax making the interval explicit :

```
 f[a_] := Evaluate[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, a}]]
```

This way, you will avoid the addition of a constant (for more complex functions than x^2) and you will prevent the evaluation of Integrate each time : the Integration calculation will be attempted when you create the function, not when you supply the argument.